# How to plot average per day from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have to create a visualization from Prometheus metrics. I have a counter metrics `http_request_counter`, I wanted to show a summary of total requests served in a day. This is how I did when we had graphite as our data source.

```
alias(summarize(sumSeries(consolidateBy(nonNegativeDerivative(http_request_counter.count), 'sum')), '1d', 'sum', false), 'TPS per day')
```

I saw few documentations and tried with `increase(http_requests_total[24h])` which plotted the graph with `t-24h` values.

Can someone help me find an equivalent of `summarize` function in prometheus please?

Comment: What is the type of you metric ? Is it a counter, a gauge or something else ?

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA - It is a counter.

Answer (score 6):

You need `sum(increase(http_requests_total[24h]))`. It returns the summary number of requests during the *last* 24 hours for every point on the graph. By default Grafana queries many points from Prometheus in order to draw smooth graph for the current horizontal resolution of the graph. The number of points on the graph can be adjusted with the `min step` option when editing the graph in Grafana. Another option is to use [subqueries](https://valyala.medium.com/prometheus-subqueries-in-victoriametrics-9b1492b720b3) with the desired step for the outer query:

```
last_over_time(sum(increase(http_requests_total[24h]))[1d:1d])
```

It will return continous line with one-day steps. These steps will be shifted by one day in the past, e.g. the step for the current day will contain the number of requests made on the previous day. This shift can be removed with negative `offset`:

```
last_over_time(sum(increase(http_requests_total[1d] offset -1d))[1d:1d])
```

Unfortunately, this query doesn't work out of the box in Prometheus, since it doesn't accept negative offsets by default. They [must be enabled with --enable-feature=promql-negative-offset command-line flag when starting Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/disabled_features/#negative-offset-in-promql). Fortunately, negative offsets are supported by default in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) in VictoriaMetrics - the system I work on.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure whether you want total requests per day or average req/s per day, here is expression for the latter:

```
avg_over_time(
  sum(rate(http_request_counter[5m])) by (method, some_other_label)[1d]
)
```

Since it is a counter, you need to apply rate to get a per-second vector, then use sum if needed to aggregate across multiple series on some labels, and at last average over one day.

Comment: I need the total requests per day.